# Find specific string in List<>

Tags: c#, linq, list

I'm working with my `List<SharepointFieldMapper> iList` as you can see below:

[image]

Now what I'm trying to reach is:

```
 public string getStaticName(string SPFriendlyName)
 {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SPFriendlyName))
    {
        foreach (SharepointFieldMapper x in iList)
        {            
            if (string.Equals(iList.FindAll(FriendlyName); (SPFriendlyName)){} //Didn't run

            result = iList.Find(x => x.FriendlyName.Contains(SPFriendlyName))); // Didn't run either
        }
 }
```

Basically what I'm trying to to is search the List for the Value of SPFriendlyName I have as parameter. But both attempts showed an empty result.

I don't bother if it's Linq or not.

Comment: That IsNullOrEmpty check should be done outside of the loop, it's result will never be different from one iteration to the next.

Comment: As a side note, your `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SPFriendlyName))` should be outside the `foreach`.

Comment: "both attempts didn't went good" - Here is the point your question went wrong. :P What was the problem?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your code and step through it to see what's happening. If it "didn't run" then it's likely it didn't satisfy a condition necessary to reach that code.

Comment: thanks guys, i've changed the code, @Octopoid the result was just false with the if, the other one didn't had problems with the x??

Comment: The line with the `if` will syntax error, it has a `;` right in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to get the first `FriendlyName` in the list which is `SPFriendlyName`:

```
string firstmatchingFriendlyName  = iList
    .Where(x => x.FriendlyName == SPFriendlyName)
    .Select(x => x.FriendlyName)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(null) // specify the replacement value
    .First();
```

This searaches the first `SharepointFieldMapper` where the `FriendlyName` equals the parameter and selects this string-property. `DefaultIfEmpty` allows to specify a replacement value which is used if there is none with that name. `Enumerable.First` either selects the first match or the replacement value.